# iOS VPN using the MS Defender app

Tags: ios, vpn

Has anyone noticed the MS Defender app VPN not working on the iPhone?   The iPhone actually shows the VPN is connected, but in WiFiMan the phone shows connected to the cell co. With the VPN server missing? Wondering if this started after the iOS 16 upgrade, I did the other day, did not really pay attention.  The Cloudflare and Google VPN working fine

[image]

Comment: I am in Athens right now.  My usual T-Mobile Esim to US shoes the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The defender vpn started working again per wifiman (other net tools also). For several days a lot of people did not have VPN connection, even though their iPhone showed they did…
[image]

Comment: So basically the problem solved itself without user intervention?

Comment: Microsoft fixed the issue.  Their vpn service was out for few days.  Same timing with the iOS 16 upgrade.   Not sure if related though

Comment: Yes nohillside, no user intervention